# Allowing 3rd party applications to validate users and bearer tokens against my asp.net web api application

Tags: authentication, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I have the following scenario, and couldn't find anything with Google searches so this is my last resort.

What my intention is:

I want to create a single ASP.NET Web API project that implements ASP.NET Identity. So I have created numerous versions of these kinds of implementations the past few months, so the basics I understand, but what I want to do now is have a single point of login and user validation that multiple projects can use in the future.

So I have implemented the basic project that exposes the bearer token on the end point "/Token" with the whole grant_type=password but now I am stuck.

If I now create another project and I want to secure that project without implementing it all again, and not allowing access to the users database to that project, how would I go about it.

So Project 1 is the asp.net identity implementation.

Project 2 needs to secure it's controllers by validating against project 1, but I have no idea where to start looking, and can't really find any decent answers on Google, please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would simply plug your default aspnet roles and userdatabase connection of Project B to project A's aspnet userdatabase's connection string.. both applications would use same userdatabase and same tokens.

Comment: I would prefer not to share the database

Comment: hmm what if you create a second project in a subfolder, and you will have to get a token on /subfolder/token

Comment: That could work but would force all projects to be in these sub folders or have these subfolders, maybe some form of oauth or something would do the trick?